# How do I use this singleton example

Tags: c#

This page does a good job of describing how to create c# singletons, but it doesn't seem to explain how you actually use them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

So if I were to create this singleton below, how do I kick things off (I don't think I can instantiate it directly) and if I don't have an instance object how to I access it - e.g. how do I read and write to property `prop1`

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         return instance; 
      }
   }

   public int prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the distinction between a static and non-static member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a singleton class, you simply call it's public static instance property. For example, suppose that you have a logger, and you don't want other developers to always instantiating it:

```
public class Logger
{
    private static Logger logger = new Logger();

    private Logger() { }

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return logger;
        }
    }

    public void Log(text)
    {
        // Logging text
    }

    public int Mode { get; set; }
}
```

You should log this way:

```
Logger.Instance.Log("some text here");
```

In your case, to read/write `Mode` property, you should write:

```
Logger.Instance.Mode = 1;
int mode = Logger.Instance.Mode;
```

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the instance by using

```
Singleton.Instance
```

Comment: You say I am creating a new instance each time I get the instance. Are you sure. I definately dont want to create multiple instances as this is a singleton.

Comment: Sorry I missed read your example, have removed that bit from my answer

Comment: No You are not creating the singleton instance multiple times.each time you call Singleton.Instance it will return the existing one.

Comment: @spiderplant0 He is not implying what you are saying. You will get the singleton instance by accessing the `instance` property

Comment: @ Björn Roberg. My comments refer to a previous version of the answer. Anyway is all cleared up now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Singleton.Instance.prop1 = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only create the instance once, So you will have something like this

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static readonly Singleton instance;
   private bool initialised = false; 

   private Singleton(){}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
        if(initialised)
          return instance; 
        else {
               initialsed = true;
               instance = new Singleton();
               return instance; 
             }
      }
   }

   public int prop1 {get; set;}
}
```